# Selecting single rows that have max value for each unique name in different column

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count

I need to find a unique set of province, district (accordingly 'wojewodztwo', 'powiat')
for max value in column called 'liczba'

So basically i need to find district with the biggest value for each unique province

My data base looks like this

[image]

And I used this command

```
select 
        wojewodztwo, 
        powiat, 
        count(typmsc) as liczba 
from 
        wojewodztwa
inner join powiaty 
        on wojewodztwa.klwoj = powiaty.klwoj
inner join gminy
        on powiaty.klpow = gminy.klpow
inner join miejscowosci
        on gminy.klgm = miejscowosci.klgm 
inner join typymsc
        on miejscowosci.kltm = typymsc.kltm
where
        typmsc = 'miasto'
group by
        wojewodztwo,
        powiat
```

To obtain table that looks like this

[image]

I tried to obtain the result by using this query above and making it a temporary (`temp`) table so i can work on it that way but i couldn't come up with a solution

I want my result to look something like this

[image]

The result should have 16 rows of each unique province name (thats how many provinces my country have)

Comment: Please post the table structure in text.

Comment: I don't understand which table structure would you like me to post in text. The middle picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it

I used this query

```
select distinct on(wojewodztwo) wojewodztwo, powiat, liczba from(
        select wojewodztwo, powiat, count(typmsc) as liczba from wojewodztwa
        inner join powiaty on wojewodztwa.klwoj = powiaty.klwoj
        inner join gminy on powiaty.klpow = gminy.klpow
        inner join miejscowosci on gminy.klgm = miejscowosci.klgm 
        inner join typymsc on miejscowosci.kltm = typymsc.kltm
        where typmsc = 'miasto'
        group by wojewodztwo,powiat
) as temp 
order by wojewodztwo,liczba desc
```

And here is the output i got

[image]